# Getting data from dynamically created variables in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jframe, jtextfield

I have a Jframe that includes a Jspinner. When the JSpinner is increased a new JTextField is created in my panel headerPanel. The script creates the textboxes with an integer attached to their variable name (tFrame0, tFrame1, and so on).

Original code and all old edits moved to [This](https://pastebin.com/eYGfThcT) pastebin.

Linking the pastebin just in case it will help anyone in the future, and to not clutter the currently relevant code.

This was solved with the help of [TreffnonX](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3277386/treffnonx)! Thanks for being very patient with me in the comments and in chat.

Here is the working code in case anybody stumbles across this kind of issue later.

Global Variables

```
private JPanel headerPanel;
private JSpinner spinner;

public List<JTextField> findTextFields() {
    List<JTextField> fields = new LinkedList<>();

    Component[] children = headerPanel.getComponents();
    for (Component child : children) {
        if (child instanceof JTextField) {
            JTextField childField = (JTextField) child;

            // check, if the name is prefixed correctly.
            String name = childField.getName();
            if (name.startsWith(nameTField)) {
                fields.add(childField);
            }
        }
    }

    return fields;
}
```

JSpinner

```
spinner = new JSpinner();
spinner.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 100, 1));
    spinner.addContainerListener(new ContainerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent arg0) {
        adaptBoxes();
    }
});
spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
        int spinnerValue = (Integer) spinner.getValue();
        if (spinnerValue == headerPanel.getComponentCount()) {
            System.out.println("Error, spinner shouldn't change to same alue");
        }
        adaptBoxes();
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
});
adaptBoxes();
```

adaptBoxes(); Method

```
public void adaptBoxes() {
    // Find value of spinner.
    int spinnerValue = (Integer) spinner.getValue();

    List<JTextField> textFields = findTextFields();
    int numTextFields = textFields.size();

    if (numTextFields > spinnerValue) {
        // if we have too many fields.
        for (JTextField textField : textFields) {
            String name = textField.getName();
            Matcher matcher = POSTFIX_PATTERN.matcher(name);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                String strPostfix = matcher.group(1);
                int postFixNumeric = Integer.parseInt(strPostfix);

                System.out.println("for postFix = " + postFixNumeric + ": " + textField.getText());
                if (postFixNumeric >= spinnerValue) {
                    System.out.println("PFN: " + postFixNumeric);
                    System.out.println("FTF: " + numTextFields);
                    headerPanel.remove(textField);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        while (numTextFields < spinnerValue) {
            // if we have too few fields.
            int hp = headerPanel.getComponentCount();

            JTextField tField = new JTextField();
            tField.setName(nameTField + hp);

            tField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new TextFieldDocumentListener());

            headerPanel.add(tField);

            textFields = findTextFields();
            numTextFields = textFields.size();
        }
    }
}
```

JTextField Document Listener

```
/**
 * Inner class
 */
private final class TextFieldDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
    }

    /**
     * Actual sysout to inform the user...
     */
    public void warn() {
        List<JTextField> textFields = findTextFields();
        for (JTextField textField : textFields) {
            String name = textField.getName();

            Matcher matcher = POSTFIX_PATTERN.matcher(name);
            System.out.println(name);

            if (matcher.matches()) {
                String strPostfix = matcher.group(1);
                int postfixNumeric = Integer.parseInt(strPostfix);

                System.out.println("for postfix = " + postfixNumeric + ": " + textField.getText());
            } else {
                System.out.println("matcher error: " + matcher);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot 'append my for loop int i to a variable name', unless you want to use reflections (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html). Reflections would allow you to search a java-`Object` for it's fields, and based on their name (if exposed) access them.

Luckiely, this is not what you actually need here. You are actually looking for a way to identify the children (`Component`s) of your J?Panel both by type and name, and then deduce the index, you formerly appended. My suggestion is to do the following:

```java
// This pattern can be anywhere in the Class-file:
public static final Pattern POSTFIX_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("tFrame(\\d+)");

// This should be in your exposed GUI class (supposedly the Panel), but can be anywhere it can access headerPanel.
public List<JTextField> findTextFields() {
    List<JTextField> fields = new LinkedList<>();

    Component[] children = headerPanel.getComponents();
    // this is your 'search-loop':
    for (Component child : children) {
        if (child instanceof JTextField) {
            JTextField childField = (JTextField) child;
            String name = childField.getName();
            if (name.startsWith("tFrame")) {
                fields.add(childField);
            }
        }
    }

    return fields;
}
```

(This could also be done as with `Stream`, but the above code is simpler).

The above code 'finds' your existing components, and you can work from there, for example by sorting them, based on their names, and then doing a print.

The problem why you receive only part of your text fields seem to react to the modifications is because you (probably) don't pass the same `inputData`-array to the different `DocumentListener`s you create. if you set a breakpoint and check, I bet the inputData-Arrays have a different hash. That said, I can't deduce this 100%, since the surrounding code is incomplete.

I'd suggest to change:

```java
if (tField.getText() != null) {
    Object[] currentData = new Object[getFieldNum + 1];
    currentData[getFieldNum] = tField.getText();

    inputData[getFieldNum] = tField.getText();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
        if (inputData[i] != null) {
            System.out.println("for i = " + i + ": " + inputData[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

to

```java
for (JTextField textField : findTextFields()) {
    String name = textField.getName();
    Matcher matcher = POSTFIX_PATTERN.matcher(name);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String strPostfix = matcher.group(1);
        int postfixNumeric = Integer.parseInt(strPostfix);

        System.out.println("for postfix = " + postfixNumeric + ": " + textField.getText());
    }
}
```

This way, you get the components at the point in time when the user actually made the change you want to react to.

Also on a side note:
Do you actually want to replace all existing text fields and their current state, once you reduce or increase the number on the JSpinner?

Maybe consider to remove the elements that are `postfixNumeric >= getTextFields().size()`, or increase the number of elements without removing those that are less than the previous number on the JSpinner. That can be done with the loop you got.

## Edit

The problem turned out to originate in a multitude of instance-fields used instead of local variables. Since the code was only partially posted, this was hard to impossible to determin from the question alone.

Comment: I've tried to implement this, but I've run into a few issues. my matcher.matches() is not returning true. Also I have checked that name is the fieldName for each field and they are still only returning the most recently created JTextField.

Comment: Also yes I plan to decrease the amount of elements rather than removing them all, that was mostly just waiting until after I fix this issue.

Comment: The parameter you pass to the matcher, is it the name of the textField you are looking at? I made a fix to my code suggestion. It should match the names of your text fields, unless for some other reason your list is empty, or your textFields have different names. Expected names are: "tFrame0", "tFrame1"...

Comment: Yes, I changed the `if (name.startsWith("tFrame"))` to `if (name.startsWith(nameTField))` so it uses my name variable.

Comment: Is there a space between the number and "tFrame"? If there is, the regular expression must be "tFrame (\\d+)" instead of "tFrame(\\d+)".

Comment: No each one prints as "tFrame0, tFrame1, ..."        Edit: I did have to make String name a public String outside of findTextFields() and then assign it from within.

Comment: When you copy pasted the regular expression to your IDE did it double all the backslashes, maybe? eclipse IDE does this in newer versions. I am very curious as to why the matcher does not match your names.

Comment: It did not add double slashes. `public static final Pattern POSTFIX_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("tFrame(\\d+)");` Thinking about it though I'm going to change this to `public static final Pattern POSTFIX_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(nameTField + "(\\d+)");` so that it is consistent.

Comment: Hmm... this looks correct. And you are 100% sure, there are no spaces before or after the name and/or number? The matcher's `.matches()` only finds total matches, so if there are any whitespaces, it won't work.

Comment: matcher sysout `java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=null(\d+) region=0,7 lastmatch=]` perhaps I'm declaring the matcher before my nameTField

Comment: Your field `nameTField` is set too late... you set it after the constant is initialized. Maybe make `nameTField` public static final too and place it *before* the Pattern.

Comment: Yep was just editing my comment that I thought that might be it, here's hoping! Edit: this did solve the issue with the matcher! However I still have only the most recent JTextField for name and postfixNumeric

Comment: My values seem correct in the console however, am I able to access these values?
Edit: Cannot add to main post
Important part is the end
`for postfix = 1: Box 1
tField1
for postfix = 1: Box 
tField1
for postfix = 1: Box 1
tField1
for postfix = 1: Box 2`

Comment: What IDE are you using? Are you aware of breakpoints? They could be useful here (if you use eclipse, just double click on a line number on the left side of the editor to set/unset one). Then you can open the debug view, or add the Variable-view to your workbench to directly access all variables at debug time. Then start your code in debug mode instead of productive mode (it's the little beetle, instead of the arrow button).

Comment: I'm using eclipse, I haven't used breakpoints before but I'll give it a try and see what I can find. Edit, so I'm seeing that my matcher text is updating to the current JTextField each time I add one.

Comment: Assuming you printed all textFields that you encountered, and not just the ones that matched, in the comment you added on my post, something is very wrong. it can only mean, that at the point in time you add the new field, it is the ONLY field within headerPanel. I think, the effect might be as follows: #Edit2 (of my original Answer)

Comment: I'm trying this now.

Comment: I've updated my post. Now I remove the boxes based on the matching and it seems to be working just fine. However I still get the latest JTextField in my output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195129/discussion-between-treffnonx-and-fuzzyketchup).